# Unable to get notification on iOS by sendToDevice, possible with Firebase Notification Composer

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app can receive the notifications created by the Firebase Notification Composer. When I send a notification by code, it fails to receive. No callbacks or overrides of the AppDelegate are triggered. When I send it from Composer, userNotificationCenter will be called as expected.

When I switch the project in Firebase Console and use the Notification Composer of the different project, notification is not received. For this, I'm assuming the project association is correct and the iOS SDK is set up correctly to listen to the right project with right authentication credential resources such as APNs Key.

On the sender's side, I'm using this simple code to send a notification. I can use the same fcm_token in the Composer to receive the message, so I'm also assuming that the fcm_token is the right one.

```
      var payload = {
        data: {
            title: "Welcome to My Group",
            message: "You may have new messages"
        }
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(<fcm_token>, payload);
```

My project also sends notifications to the webapps. The same code above sends a message that can be received by my web-app, so I'm sure that the message is sending correctly as well.

Does anybody know the difference between the notification created by the Notification Composer and one created with sendToDevice?